# org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible with chrome=66.0.3359.139 and chromedriver=2.36.540470

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have to set value to "Gross Amount" field.But this field is having regular 
 expressions on that and when we enter value and move to next field , the 
 entered value is converting as "$1000.00" formate. Here is 1000 has given as 
 example.

Below are keywords:

```
public boolean setValue(String LType, String Locator, String value, 
    String Expected) {

    By by = null;
    if (LType.length() < 2) {
        by = By(Locator);
    } else {
        by = By(LType, Locator);
    }

    WebElement element = null;

    try {
        if ((element = isElementPresent(by)) != null) {

            element.sendKeys("value",value);
            return true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Exception while SendKeys on element" + LType + " " + 
  Locator, e);
    }
    return false;
  }



public boolean isElementPresent(String LType, String Locator, String value, 
String Expected) {

    By by = null;
    if (LType.length() < 2) {
        by = By(Locator);
    } else {
        by = By(LType, Locator);
    }
    WebElement element = null;
    try {

        if ((isElementPresent(by)) != null) {

            return true;
        }
    } catch (WebDriverException e) {
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollTo(0," + 
   element.getLocation().y + ")");
        element.click();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Exception while isElementPresent element" + LType + " " 
 + Locator, e);
    }
    return false;
}
```

And HTML Code:This Html code is having some regular expressions

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="GrossAmount">Gross Amount</label>


<input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Gross Amount must be a number." data-val-regex="Field accepts a positive number with a maximum of 17 digits including 2 decimals." data-val-regex-pattern="\d{0,15}(\.\d{1,2})?" id="GrossAmount" name="GrossAmount" style="display: none;" type="text" value="">
<input class="form-control" id="GrossAmount_C" name="GrossAmount.C" style="display: block;" type="text" value="">
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('#GrossAmount').focusout(function () { CurrencyFocusOut('GrossAmount_C', this) });
        $('#GrossAmount_C').focus(function () { CurrencyResultFocus('GrossAmount', this) });
        CurrencyKeyPress('#GrossAmount');
    });
</script>
            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="GrossAmount" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>


<!-- end snippet -->
```

Code is working fine in debug mode and setting value where as in run mode it is 
 not working

Error stack trace:

```
ERROR : 2018-06-14 18:12:33 : Driver.setNum():746 - Exception while SendKeys on element //input[@id='GrossAmount_C'] org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible (Session info: chrome=66.0.3359.139) (Driver info: chromedriver=2.36.540470 (e522d04694c7ebea4ba8821272dbef4f9b818c91)
```

Request you to help on this.

Comment: Whats the stack trace? Any Run parameters?

Comment: yes I am passing parameters through excel....parameters are like xpath,value....based on our requirement

Comment: What i am saying is that if the code is working in debug mode but not in normal mode, there must be some configuration or deployement issue. Is there a stack trace?

Comment: Below is the log file:   ERROR : 2018-06-13 19:44:35 : Driver.setNum():745 - Exception while SendKeys on element //input[@id='GrossAmount_C']
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot focus element
  (Session info: chrome=66.0.3359.139)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.36.540470 (e522d04694c7ebea4ba8821272dbef4f9b818c91),

Comment: Error is showed as "Can not focus  element" , but i am able to click on that element and at the same time in UI we are able to see the focus on element.

Comment: Malformed _HTML_, `div class="form-group"` missing _starting tag_

Comment: That's my mistake ..i have pasted wrongly..actually it is present in DOM

Comment: @Padmajapalle Untill and unless you tag me within your comments towards my answers I am not updated if there is a reply from your side. Can you consider to provide the correct _HTML_ else debugging becomes harder

Comment: @DebanjanB ,I have provided Outer HTML for Grosss Amount field and I could see as it is having JQuery.

Comment: @DebanjanB ,Any idea to set value for the field

Comment: @Padmajapalle Ahhh, I did had some inputs for you possibly an answer but I am yet to work on your usecase. Gimme some time please

Comment: @DebanjanB, could you please provide me the solutions which you are having?

Comment: @DebanjanB, Hi ..solutions pls

Answer (score 0):

You can try to click and enter value on focused element as given below.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("GrossAmount_C")).click();
driver.switchTo().activeElement().sendKeys("1000");
```

or

```
driver.switchTo().activeElement().sendKeys(Keys.chord("1000"));
```

Comment: Thnks Murthi...I have tried the same both in debug and run mode but samething is happening as it is working in debug mode and not in run mode

Comment: getting  this error in logs:ERROR : 2018-06-14 18:12:33 : Driver.setNum():746 - Exception while SendKeys on element //input[@id='GrossAmount_C']
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=66.0.3359.139)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.36.540470 (e522d04694c7ebea4ba8821272dbef4f9b818c91)

Comment: Use wait before sendkeys

Comment: Tried the same and got this error :org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: invalid element state: Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated
  (Session info: chrome=66.0.3359.139)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.36.540470 (e522d04694c7ebea4ba8821272dbef4f9b818c91),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 37 milliseconds

Comment: @ Ankur Singh, How to set value for the fileds which are having jQuery on that? I have edited HTML code with jQuery

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot focus element (Session info: chrome=66.0.3359.139) (Driver info: chromedriver=2.36.540470 (e522d04694c7ebea4ba8821272dbef4f9b818c91)
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver v2.36** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** i.e. **Chrome Browser v66.0** session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.36*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.36*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.36/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v63-65**

- You are using *chrome=66.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v2.40*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.40/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v66-68**

- Your *Selenium Client* version is **unknown** to us.

So there is a clear mismatch between **ChromeDriver v2.36** and the **Chrome Browser v66.0**

### Solution

- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u171**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).
- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.12.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.40**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version between ***Chrome v66-68*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.40 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.40/notes.txt))
- Execute your `@Test`.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.